# Eclipse e4 part toolbar only shows when Part is in Part Stack?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

so I would want to add a toolbar to my part, but the toolbar only appears if the part is in a Part Stack. 
If it is the case, the part toolbar is shown but also the minimize maximize controls and the Part Stack heder thing, which is normal, but has this special eclipse- or RCP look which I would want to avoid.

Does anyone know how to add a toolbar via the application model or otherwise, with just the toolbaritems showing and nothing else ?

Lars Vogel [shows how](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#toolbar_advanced_buttons) to add a toolbar item, but he doesn't mention that it will only work for Parts in Part Stacks ...
[image: screenshot from vogella]

btw: I using eclipse Luna with e4 tools 0.15

Comment: It does look like it is the StackRenderer that deals with showing the part toolbar. If you are using a Trimmed Window you can have TrimBar with a toolbar.

Comment: The thing is that it is a plugin-project and the part is in an PartSashContainer. The application is using a Trimmed Window, how can I embed a TrimBar into my part? is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the standard SWT renderers, the toolbar of a `Part` will only be rendered if the `Part` ist in a `PartStack`. The reason for this is that it is the `PartStackRenderer` that creates to toolbar and switches it if a different `part`is selected.

What you can do is put the `Part` in a `PartStack` and then put the `PartStack` inside of the `PartSashContainer`.

If you want to render the toolbar of a `Part` inside of a toolbar of your `TrimmedWindow`, you would need to write your own renderer for `TrimmedWindow`. Here you can scan for embedded parts that need to show their toolbar and then react accordingly.